# Design Me Area In SAPUI5 Page Header

Tags: sapui5

According to the latest Fiori design guidelines, there is a new concept called [Me Area](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/me-area/) which contains *user-specific* and *context-aware* information and *shortcuts*.

But, there is no documentation or reference to get that control. Has anyone able to apply that on to their SAPUI5 Page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Me Area* is part of the SAP Fiori Launchpad, and not a UI control in the SAPUI5 library. Technically, it is a view with name `sap.ushell.components.shell.MeArea.MeArea`.

Comment: Me Area is also visible if you use the Cloud Portal (FLP in the Cloud) on SAP Cloud Platform while hosting your UI5 Application and deploying it to the Cloud FLP.

Comment: thats a bummer..but what can we do :(